# Can't get league of Legends working on lubuntu

Tags: wine, launcher, games, playonlinux

I used Wine and Play on Linux, but it doesn't work. The following script is what happens when i press run on play on Linux:

```
(0x172f20) - stub
fixme:alsa:AudioSessionControl_UnregisterAudioSessionNotification (0x1770b8)->(0x172f20) - stub
[08/15/17 13:36:46] - ----- Ending function POL_Install_AdobeAir -----
[08/15/17 13:42:54] - Running wine-1.7.36 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends' has been updated.
[08/15/17 13:54:58] - Running wine-2.4 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
wine: Unhandled exception 0xe06d7363 in thread 55 at address 0x7b43ff62 (thread 0055), starting debugger...
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends' has been updated.
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[08/15/17 13:57:18] - Running wine-2.4 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
wine: Unhandled exception 0xe06d7363 in thread 15d at address 0x7b43ff62 (thread 015d), starting debugger...
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[08/15/17 13:58:02] - Running wine-1.7.36 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends' has been updated.
[08/15/17 13:58:47] - Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wine: configuration in '/home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends' has been updated.
[08/15/17 13:59:05] - Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
[08/18/17 10:14:22] - Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
[08/18/17 10:16:28] - Running wine-1.9.2-LeagueOfLegends5 lol.launcher.admin.exe (Working directory : /home/sweglord/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/LeagueOfLegends/drive_c/Riot Games/League of Legends)
err:winedevice:ServiceMain driver L"WineBus" failed to load
fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f918 1 C) semi-stub
fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f758 1 C) semi-stub
fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0x33f8c4 1 C) semi-stub
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {2f9efe86-4af7-4f37-a40f-94b909a157d6}, 0x484200, 0x6851d0, 0x68e5d0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {ea08c559-95a8-4aa2-afa6-18738eec6d37}, 0x484200, 0x685198, 0x68e5c8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {10f6728c-ef92-4bf1-8397-49e693a6eb74}, 0x484200, 0x685208, 0x68e520
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {46dd7f96-60cb-416b-8085-da5cd8f491dd}, 0x484200, 0x685240, 0x68e608
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fcbc (nil)): stub
err:wincodecs:PngDecoder_CreateInstance Failed reading PNG because unable to find libpng12.so.0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {2f9efe86-4af7-4f37-a40f-94b909a157d6}, 0x100555b0, 0x100906c0, 0x10094ad0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {ea08c559-95a8-4aa2-afa6-18738eec6d37}, 0x100555b0, 0x10090768, 0x10094ac8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {10f6728c-ef92-4bf1-8397-49e693a6eb74}, 0x100555b0, 0x100906f8, 0x10094b10
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {46dd7f96-60cb-416b-8085-da5cd8f491dd}, 0x100555b0, 0x10090730, 0x10094b08
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {2f9efe86-4af7-4f37-a40f-94b909a157d6}, 0x4b1c90, 0x89ad10, 0x8d9e10
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {ea08c559-95a8-4aa2-afa6-18738eec6d37}, 0x4b1c90, 0x89adb8, 0x8d9e08
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {10f6728c-ef92-4bf1-8397-49e693a6eb74}, 0x4b1c90, 0x89ad48, 0x8d9e50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {46dd7f96-60cb-416b-8085-da5cd8f491dd}, 0x4b1c90, 0x89ad80, 0x8d9e48
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f1b4 (nil)): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformationEx (0x0000006b,0x33ee10,4,(nil),0,0x8d55e4) stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33e534 (nil)): stub
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
```

fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33ef44 (nil)): stub

Answer (score 0):

tips for POL:

- try different windows version
- try different wine version (I'm using 2.1staging)
- use a virtual desktop in wine settings with your screen dimensions
- disable "close client during game" in LoL settings
- install internet explorer to get the shop working

alternative:

- use lutris: https://lutris.net/games/league-of-legends/
- visit https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/

Answer (score 0):

These steps have proven to work

### wine

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install wine
```

The Ubuntu Wine ppa supports all of Ubuntu distros.

### PlayOnLinux

PlayOnLinux is a piece of software which allows you to easily install and use numerous games and apps designed to run with Microsoft® Windows®. Few games are compatible with GNU/Linux at the moment and it certainly is a factor preventing the migration to this system. PlayOnLinux brings a cost-free, accessible and efficient solution to this problem.
PlayOnLinux

```
wget -q "https://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget https://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_precise.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

After everything is installed, run playonlinux, press the install button, select the Testing option, after that search for League of Legends, press install

[image: PlayOnLinux]

Then select Download the program. the installer will be downloaded and then excecuted. Do not change the default location of the installation.

Do not launch League of Legends, after the completion of the installation. Run lol via the icon on your desktop.

---

This is an excerpt of [League of Legends under Ubuntu(updated) - EuroBytes](https://eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu)

Which I am the author of

Answer (score 0):

> err:wincodecs:PngDecoder_CreateInstance Failed reading PNG because unable to find libpng12.so.0

Try installing/re-installing `libpng` package, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install libpng
```